# sending variable to a javascript file in RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using ajax to call a RoR rails function and am new to this.

The function is

```
def destroy
   @fav_company = FavouriteCompany.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render :layout=>false }
    end
end
```

In my destroy.js.erb I have

```
 $('#profile_alerts').show();
 $('#Fav#{@fav_company.id}').hide();
```

The first line is working but not the second line. I am suspecting it is unable to access @fav_company.

What should I do? thanks

=====

Some additional information, the call I am making to this function is a link_to with remote => 'true' as such:

```
<%=link_to "destroy",{:controller=>"favourite_companies",:action=>"destroy", :id=>"#{fav.id}"}, {:remote => true } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$('#Fav#{escape_javascript({@fav_company.id}).html_safe}').hide();
```

==================================================================================

Ok, my code, but I does another task:

albums/show.html.haml

```
= link_to t('write.comment'),  new_album_comment_path(@album, :format => :js, :id => @album.id), :remote => true
```

comments/new.js.haml

```
$("#comment_form").html("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => "comments/form").html_safe}");
```

also all code here https://github.com/barthezslavik/mebel - if you found something useful, I'll be happy

Comment: Then you need to post your views and all related stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
$('#Fav#{@fav_company.id}').hide();
```

Should be:

```
 $('#Fav #{@fav_company.id}').hide();
```

Assuming `@fav_company.id` presents a variable in the DOM

Comment: thanks. the id's of the divs are actually titled something like "Fav1232" but I played around with your suggestion and it didn't work. Perhaps I'm not passing the variable in right?

Answer (score 3):

Since your javascript code is in an ERB file I think you should be using `$('#Fav<%=@fav_company.id%>').hide();`.